# Get last inserted ID in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, linq, wcf-data-services, ria

```
    DomainServiceAccountManager d = new DomainServiceAccountManager();
    Web.Buy b=new Web.Buy();
    b.ID_member = IDMemberToBuy;
    b.Money = MoneyBuy;
    b.Tarikh = tarikh;
    b.Hesab = false;
    d.Buys.Add(b);
    d.SubmitChanges(op => { if (!op.HasError) MessageBox.Show(b.ID.ToString()); });
```

But I'm getting this error:

> No overload for method 'SubmitChanges' takes 1 arguments
>
> C:\Users\farzad\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\AccountManager\AccountManager\Views\Login\CWBuy.xaml.cs 214 13  AccountManager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two [`SubmitChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422910%28v=vs.91%29) methods.

The [first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422324%28v=vs.91%29) takes **no** arguments, while the [second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423067%28v=vs.91%29) takes **two**.

You need to pass a second argument - `Object` (which represents the user state) to your call.